# Async task can't update GUI

Tags: java, android

My basic question is how do you update the GUI with AsyncTask.  I am setting a `String` in `onPostExecute` that the GUI thread references.  Using logging, I can see the `String` getting set in the `onPostExecute` method, but it never gets set on my GUI under my `onClickListener` to update the GUI.  Any help is appreciated.

Main Program:

> public class Main extends Activity {
>
> ```
> /** Called when the activity is first created. */
> Arduino.ToAndroid.Temperature.GetJSON jsonHttpClass = new Arduino.ToAndroid.Temperature.GetJSON();
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
>     new GetJSON().execute(url_to_Http);
> }
> View.OnClickListener temperatureListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
>     public void onClick(View v) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         // buttonTemperature = json.getTemp();
>         tempView.setText(jsonHttpClass.value);
>         Log.i("ROSS LOG", "Button Clicked");
>     }
> }; }
> ```

Async Task:

> class GetJSON extends AsyncTask {
>
> ```
> public String value;
>
> @Override
> protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
>     String result = this.getHttpJson(url[0]);
>     return result;
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>     value = new String(result);
>     Log.i("ROSS LOG", value);
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: It's not clear at what point your `temperatureListener` is being added to your button view. Is the "Button Clicked" log message appearing when you click your button?

Comment: I was using temperatureListener as a button to update the GUI.  Yes, the 'button clicked' log message appears.  Deepak was able to find my problem, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreate()`, you should be using the handle for the already created object of the `AsyncTask` and not create a new object.

Use

```
jsonHttpClass.execute(url_to_Http);
```

instead of

```
new GetJSON().execute(url_to_Http);
```

Comment: That was exactly it.  I should have caught that.

THANKS!